# Checking exceptions thrown by external Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I have a data form that performs some calculations upon button press. Once this button is pressed, an object of a static class is instantiated. This object calls different methods in various other classes too.

I have designed these classes in such a way that if any error is thrown, the exception would be handled and the class method would display the error message in asp:ValidationSummary.
Now, when from this data form, i try to save my values, even though, the validationSummary is displaying errors on the forms, the invalid values get saved in the database.

I can create a static property called IsValid in this external class, which is set to false everytime an exception is thrown by the method, however since these methods are repeatedly called by the objects, this property is set back to true if there isn't any exception thrown, thus resulting in bypass of IF condition.

Is there a way to handle such scenario?

Here is the method that is throwing exceptions. This method belongs to a class ClsOmChallan. The .dll file is refered in my project, nothing else.

```
public static double getResultFromAstmTables(string TableName, double ObserveTemp, double ObserveGravity)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(clsConnection.ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "select result from astm_tables where table_no = '" + TableName + "' and temperature = '" + ObserveTemp + "' and gravity = '" + ObserveGravity + "'";

        try
        {

            conn.Open();

            double result1;
            result1 = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            isValid = true;
            return result1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ValidationError.Display("clsAstmTables + getResultsFromAstmTables " + ex.Message.ToString());
            isValid = false;
            return 0;

        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't quite follow what you've done. Can you provide a little code?

Comment: Why are you attempting to do this in a static? Why not put it in an object?

Comment: ok lets say i put in an object. what benefit will i get? this method is called from another object from another class. so the heirarchy of method call is something like this : WebPage -> ConversionObject -> getResultsfromAstmTable. how will i handle exceptions in webpage? Moreover, this static function is called from various other classes, and if i put it in an object i will have to change all other classes too.

Comment: The benefit is that you create an object for each operation you want to perform. Then you can see that one operation that has failed. Otherwise, you run into the exact issue you have when you have lots of operations going back and forth

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use validator that will call your validation method on server side. Validator know to show validation summary and stop page processing.

Also, you can try

```
 public override void Validate() {
            //put your logic here
            // Now perform validation

            base.Validate();
        }
```

For more details, review [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx).

Comment: I have checked the link. This doesn't apply to my scenario.